# Set attribute selected to dropdown menu using global variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have created one dropdown menu like this

```
 <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="range">Select Maximum Range</label>
         <select name="range" id="range" data-native-menu="false">
          <option value="10" >10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
         </select>
      </fieldset>
```

I want to select option 30 using variable in jquery. I did it like this.

```
$("[value='+range+']").attr("selected", "true");
```

Here the value of range is 30. Where am i wrong?

Comment: `$("#range:option[value='+ range + ']").attr("selected", "true");`

Comment: `$("#range").val(range);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
$("[value="+range+"]").prop('selected', true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DZEdt/)**

or

```
$("#range").val(range);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DZEdt/1/)**

**Update:**

for mobile, use `$("#range").selectmenu("refresh", true);` to refresh and load the changes of select.

Comment: actually i am using jquery mobile. i looked at ur jsfiddle its working fine there but not in my page. what may be the reason?

Comment: @insanity: for mobile use `$("#range").selectmenu("refresh", true);` to refresh and load the changes in jquery mobile

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate your `range` variable properly here:

```
$("[value='" + range + "']").attr("selected", "true");
// --      ^ add this  ^
```

Also, it's better to use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of `.attr()`:

```
$("[value='" + range + "']").prop("selected", "true");
```

or you can also use **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** to set the value of your `select`:

```
$("#range").val(range);
```

---

Based on your comment, you can make use of `localStorage`:

```
$('#range').change(function () {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedOption", this.value);
});

var selectedOption = localStorage.getItem("selectedOption");
if (selectedOption) {
    $("#range").val(selectedOption);
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s67x5/3/)**

Comment: its not working . I am storing the selected option in a global variable in javascript. And i want it next time when user visits this page he will see the previous selected value.

Comment: Thanks Felix. Actually i am using phonegap. I did it using `localStorage.setItem("range", document.getElementById("range").value);` and `range = localStorage.getItem("range");` As Milind suggested i have added `$("#range").selectmenu("refresh", true);` line and it works fine. Once again thanks for nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to select the given option since you have the value of the option in the variable

```
$("#range").val(range);
```